# Artigos definidos antecedendo nomes próprios estrageiros

Tags: gramática, artigos-definidos

É bastante comum, principalmente em obras audiovisuais estrangeiras, **não** utilizar os devidos artigos definidos antes de um nome:

> Gordon is the detective in charge of this case

Ao traduzir essa frase, deve-se incluir o artigo **o** antes do nome próprio?

Talvez um exemplo um pouco mais elaborado pra demonstrar minha dúvida:

> But Gordon already took him in custody, for god's sakes!

Em português ficaria meio estranho:

> Mas Gordon já levou ele sob custódia, pelo amor de deus!

Ao passo que o com o artigo correto:

> Mas o Gordon já levou ele sob custódia, pelo amor de deus!

A frase flui melhor e fica mais expressivo.

Comment: Bruno, eu diria "já o levou".

Comment: Mas nesse caso o artigo estaria se referindo à quem foi levado e não à quem levou

Comment: Eu quis dizer que eu diria "já o levou" ao invés de "já levou ele"

Comment: Em "já o levou", o _o_ é um pronome pessoal do caso oblíquo, e não um artigo.

Comment: @RamonMelo  Eu sei que não é artigo. É claro que é um pronome pessoal oblíquo. Parece que ninguém entendeu o que eu quis dizer.  Vou tentar novamente: O OP escreveu "Gordon já levou ele".  Nessa frase eu não usaria o pronome pessoal do caso reto.  Eu usaria o pronome oblíquo, "já o levou".  Esse comentário nada tem a ver com artigo.

Comment: @Centaurus A mensagem foi direcionada ao OP. Como ele é notificado automaticamente, não usei a menção. Peço desculpas por causar o mal-entendido.

Comment: Eu diria "Mas o Gordon já o levou sob custódia, pelo amor de Deus."

Answer (score 1):

Em pt-BR é mais comum o artigo antes de nomes próprios - a Teresa, a Letícia, o Paulo, etc. E eu costumo dizer: "fomos até a casa da Teresa ontem".  Em algumas regiões do Brasil, no entanto, o povo tem uma tendência a omitir o artigo e dizer "fomos à casa de ..."

"O Gordon" ou "o Stephen" soam algo estranho aos meus ouvidos talvez porque são nomes ingleses e que habitualmente não são precedidos por artigo naquela língua, mas devem sê-lo quando traduzimos o texto para o português.

Comment: Acho problemática a generalização aqui. Há um artigo do Pasquale Cipro Neto que alega haver uma divisão bem igualitária, talvez até favorecendo a ausência do artigo: http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/fsp/cotidian/ff2810201003.htm

Comment: E a maioria dos órgãos públicos brasileiros também sugere a ausência do artigo: https://www12.senado.leg.br/manualdecomunicacao/redacao-e-estilo/estilo/artigo-definido

Comment: @RamonMelo   Procurei mas não encontrei, no artigo do Pasquale, a parte que diz a divisão ser bem igualitária.  Note bem que só os estados de São Paulo e Rio de Janeiro tem uma população maior do que a dos nove estados do Nordeste.   Por outro lado, eu não generalizei.  Na minha região (sudeste) usa-se o artigo, mas citei que em outras regiões ele não é usado.

Comment: O segundo link é para a SECOM, com diretrizes de redação e estilo.  Não se trata da língua falada.  Não se trata do povo.  Trata-se da forma jornalística como o Senado Federal quer padronizar a redação de seus funcionários.

Comment: São Paulo é um dos estados que não usam o artigo (exceto em caso de intimidade), segundo o Pasquale. Aqui no RJ, só é comum o artigo na capital. Mesmo na região metropolitana, é incomum o uso do artigo (e é assim que identificamos a origem do interlocutor). Sobre o link do Senado (para manter num único comentário), de fato, não se trata da língua falada, mas uma evidência de que a norma "culta" favorece a ausência do artigo. Também sou a favor do artigo, mas acredito que a tradução mais adequada - na ausência de maiores esclarecimentos por parte do OP - seria a versão sem artigo.

Comment: @RamonMelo   Insisto que no aqui no Rio de Janeiro, tanto na capital quanto em outras cidades, predomina o uso do artigo antes de nomes próprios.  No meio rural é que a ausência do artigo ainda é mais observada.   São observações pessoais, minhas.  Mas se você tiver uma fonte que prove o contrário, eu incorporo na minha resposta.

Comment: Eu não tenho uma fonte porque se trata de observação pessoal (e, portanto, anedotal), mas agora estou curioso pela sua experiência. Vamos mover esta discussão para o chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50834/discussion-between-ramon-melo-and-centaurus).

Comment: Isto é um post para discussão de assuntos relacionados com o português de Portugal. Não do Brasil.