# Crase em dedicatória, e regência de "proporcionar"

Tags: gramática

## Dedicatória

> A Cristina.

As dedicatórias escrevem-se sem crase, obviamente, certo?

## Agradecimentos

> Ao Prof. Dr. X, por seu inesgotável conhecimento, sua dedicação,
>     excelência, seriedade.  Investigar a ciência é um privilégio custoso;
>     investigá-la sobre ombros de gigantes é um privilégio sem preço.
>     Agradeço a Deus pela oportunidade de trabalhar com o senhor, por seu
>     carinho e amizade.
>
> A meu querido pai, eterno companheiro, com quem sempre estarei.  A
>     minha querida mãe, por seu carinho incondicional.  A meus queridos
>     irmãos, por compartilharem suas vidas comigo e me proporcionarem
>     compartilhar a minha, que é o perfume da vida.  A minha família e
>     amigos, pela plenitude de minha vida.
>
> A Deus, por tudo.

A gramática desta dedicatória está correta? Tenho estas hesitações ou dúvidas:

- Assumo que o verbo agradecer esteja implícito em todas elas.
- Em frases como "A Deus, por tudo", a vírgula ali é necessária?
- A regência de "proporcionar" está mesmo correta ali?

Comment: Idealmente, escreverias duas perguntas separadas: uma sobre "as dedicatórias levam crase?" e uma sobre "estes agradecimentos estão gramaticalmente bem escritos"?

Comment: Editei a estruturação da pergunta para a tentar tornar mais atrativa. Vê se concordas com as alterações, e (claro!) corrige-as se discordares.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is editing.

Comment: @Lambie, do you disagree that the question fits the scope of the second topic «Usage, grammar(, and pronunciation, including dialect differences)» from the ["on topic"](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help page? If you feel that these type of questions don't belong in the community, do you want to open that discussion up on meta?

Comment: @ANeves No, because I think it is clear that proofreading is off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As dedicatórias escrevem-se sem crase, obviamente, certo?

O uso de artigos com nomes próprios tem alguma variação. Na minha variedade (português europeu padrão), a resposta é **não** — tratando-se de uma pessoa com quem tens intimidade, da mesma forma que escreves *Ao (a + o) João*, também tens de escrever *À (a + a) Cristina*. Se fosse alguém mais afastado, a quem não tratarias somente pelo primeiro nome, já seria admissível ou mesmo recomendável deixar de fora o artigo (mas sempre *ao Prof.*, *ao Dr.*, *ao Sr.*, etc.).

Ver também [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3993/artigos-definidos-antecedendo-nomes-pr%C3%B3prios/4002#4002).

> Assumo que o verbo agradecer esteja implícito em todas elas.

Sim, é comum omiti-lo.

> Em frases como "A Deus, por tudo", a vírgula ali é necessária?

Tens duas opções. Ou escreves *Ao Prof. A por X. Aos meus pais por Y.* ou *Ao Prof. A, por X. Aos meus pais, por Y.*. Como usaste a vírgula nas outras frases, deves também usá-la aqui.

Em minha opinião, é mais feliz estilisticamente usar a vírgula, como fizeste.

> A regência de "proporcionar" está mesmo correta ali?

Boa questão. A mim, o uso de *proporcionar* com uma oração infinitiva como argumento parece-me marginal. O dicionário de regimes de Francisco Fernandes também não tem nenhum exemplo do género. Mas encontram-se alguns exemplos no Corpus CETEMPúblico, os quais também não me soam muito bem:

> - Entre os pequenos (PSN, PRD e PSR) , destacam-se os solidários-nacionais, que parecem estar a consolidar a posição que lhes garantiu a eleição de um deputado nas últimas legislativas e, mais recentemente, lhes **proporcionou colocar** um representante na Assembleia Regional da Madeira.
> - Só é cobrada uma taxa aos utilizadores finais, que ajudam a suportar os custos de gestão e manutenção das redes a que acedem e que lhes **proporcionam chegar** à Internet, como é o caso do PUUG (Portuguese Unix Users Group) , em Portugal.

O problema é talvez semântico, mais do que gramatical. A definição de *proporcionar* (no dicionário de Francisco Fernandes) é *dar, oferecer, prestar; deparar, apresentar*. Daí dizermos *X proporcionou (a alguém) a oportunidade/o privilégio/o ensejo/facilidades*, etc. *Compartilhar a vida* não é algo que possa ser dado.

Eu substituiria *proporcionarem* por *permitirem* ou por *proporcionarem o privilégio de*.